# Why I get the "class Num a where" instead of the "class (Eq a, Show a) => Num a"?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I learn Haskell. I send the command into ghci: `:info Num`.

```
ghci> :info Num
class Num a where
(+) :: a -> a -> a
(*) :: a -> a -> a
(-) :: a -> a -> a
negate :: a -> a
abs :: a -> a
signum :: a -> a
fromInteger :: Integer -> a
-- Defined in `GHC.Num'
instance Num Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Num'
instance Num Int -- Defined in `GHC.Num'
instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
```

I expected to see something like that: `class (Eq a, Show a) => Num a`, but I see `class Num a where`. I was surprised... Ok, I open the Hoogle and try to find info for the `Num` class type. I got [this result](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Num). I see the `class (Eq a, Show a) => Num a` in the first record of searching result. But when I open the sources I see:

```
-- | Basic numeric class.
--
-- Minimal complete definition: all except 'negate' or @(-)@
class  Num a  where
```

Why I get the `class Num a where` instead of the `class (Eq a, Show a) => Num a`?

Comment: This is probably just GHC diverging from the official language definition.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hackage showing `class (Eq a, Show a) => Num a` is probably a bug, but there really is no reason for `Num a` to require `Eq a` and `Show a`.

Comment: I don't agree with you about the "really is no reason".

Comment: @Bush Ok, why do you think `Num` should inherently require `Eq` and `Show`?

Comment: Because all numbers must to be equatable. Also it must to have capability to be printed.

Comment: @Bush For the purposes of purely arithmetic operations, like `Num` is; there's no need for `Eq` and `Show`, since neither of those have anything to do with adding, multiplying, or subtracting. It's instead up to the individual implementations to handle that. You don't see `Eq` or `Show` on the `Functor` or `Monad` typeclasses either for the same reasons

Comment: This is what Haskell 98 and Haskell 2010 specify, erroneously as it may be.

Comment: @Bush, there are no `Eq` and `Show` instances for functions, but encoding numbers by functions is a [well-known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding) trick.

Comment: @Bush Real numbers can neither be compared for equality nor converted to a (finite) string.

Comment: @augustss: Why not? Surely I can compare even an irrational number like `√2` to itself of convert it to the string representation `"sqrt(2)"`.

Comment: @Bergi [Computing equality between computable reals is uncomputable.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_analysis#Basic_results "Although we generally don't use computable reals anyway...")

Comment: @Bakuriu: Ok, thanks. I've oversimplified the problem and only thought of symbolic computation.

Answer (score 11):

I think the search index of Hoogle is pretty old.

You can see that `Eq` and `Show` superclass is removed from `Num` in these commits of `ghc`.

https://github.com/ghc/ghc/commit/0a40540e79223f38ee851c66eb377db9a1756e4b
https://github.com/ghc/ghc/commit/817c4e19a4248b80f0af764d12721b1284b39e5a

So I consider that this is the reason of the inconsistency between search result of Hoogle and actual link to Hackage.

Comment: Thank you. I see the "-class Num a => Bits a where" and "+class (Eq a, Num a) => Bits a where". As I understand - "-" is removing and "+" is adding. So I see was deleted "class Num a => Bits a where" code row and added the "class (Eq a, Num a) => Bits a where". Am I right?

Comment: @Bush that's right, and most certainly because `Bits` should still be equatable after `Num` is it no longer.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a `Num` instance for which you can't sensibly define either an `Eq` or `Show` instance -

```
instance Num r => Num (a -> r) where

    (f + g) a = f a + g a
    (f - g) a = f a - g a
    (f * g) a = f a * g a
    
    abs f = abs . f
    signum f = signum . f

    fromInteger = const . fromInteger
```

Here is a slightly more esoteric one -

```
data State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }

instance Functor (State s) where
    fmap f h = State $ \s -> let (a, s') = runState h s in (f a, s')

instance Num a => Num (State s a) where

    h + k = State $ \s -> let (a, s')  = runState h s
                              (b, s'') = runState k s'
                           in (a + b, s'')

    h * k = State $ \s -> let (a, s')  = runState h s
                              (b, s'') = runState k s'
                           in (a * b, s'')

    negate = fmap negate
    abs    = fmap abs
    signum = fmap signum

    fromInteger n = State $ \s -> (fromInteger n, s)
```

It has the unusual properties that addition and multiplication are not commutative (because each of the two arguments can arbitrarily modify the state, and the state can be arbitrarily mixed with the result returned) but otherwise it is a valid instance of `Num`.

> *Mathematical side note:* the `Num` class generally models algebraic structures called [rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) which have a commutative addition and a (not necessarily commutative) multiplication, which satisfy some compatibility rules.
>
> In this case the addition is not commutative, so it cannot be a ring. It's not even a [near-semiring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-semiring) (which is a ring with a lot of the restrictions removed) because it doesn't satisfy the distributivity law. Which raises the question - does it obey the laws of *any* reasonably well-known algebraic structure?

Both of these are examples of the more general phenomenon that any applicative can be lifted to an instance of `Num` by using `fmap` and `liftA2` -

```
instance (Num a, Applicative f) => Num (f a) where
    (+) = liftA2 (+)
    (*) = liftA2 (*)

    abs = fmap abs
    signum = fmap signum
    negate = fmap negate

    fromInteger = pure . fromInteger
```

which is a fact that I enjoy very much.

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 3):

`Num` is something that you can basically add and multiply. I think `(+)` should be a [group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_%28mathematics%29), but the [specification](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num) does not mention it.

Can you add and multiply functions? Certainly yes, if the functions yield a number.

There is no `Eq` and `Show` instance for functions in haskell, and that is why `Num` does not require those contraints.

Now you want `Ord` contraint, too? Complex numbers are `Num`s, but there is no ordering that preserves the same laws as real numbers do.

Comment: Add, multiply and negate (therefore subtract).